# Redux Error (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')) for export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

In my e-commerce web in Nextjs i am trying to implement add to basket functionality using redux but the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items'): export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;" keeps on occuring.Below is my code

Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { basketReducer } from "./Slices/basketSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    basket: basketReducer,
  },
});
```

Slices/basketSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// const initialState = {
//   items: [],
// };

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState: { items: [] },
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.items = [...state.items, action.payload];
    },
    removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {},
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket } = basketSlice.actions;
export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;
export default basketSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: One possible reason might be the selectItems function is being called before the initial state of the basket reducer has been set. Replace your `selectItems` function with this - `export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket?.items || [];`. This should prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import basketReducer from "./Slices/basketSlice";
```

in `Store.js` to import the default export as `basketReducer`. The way you have it now attempts to import an exported symbol named `basketReducer`, which doesn't exist. Alternatively, you could use

```
export const basketReducer = basketSlice.reducer;
```

in `Slices/basketSlice.js` to export the reducer under the name you're importing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within the component where you want to use this state

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
const component = () => {
  const selectItems = (state) => 
  useSelector((state)=>state.basket.items);
  return <></>;
}
```